# using cheerio, can't get attributes using .attr

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Why do I have to use link.attribs.href instead of the standard .attr('href') method?

```
...
res.on('end', () => {
     const $ = cheerio.load(content);
     const link = $('.more-link').get(0);
     // const url = link.attr('href');   <--- link.attr is not a function
     const url = link.attribs.href;       <--- works
     console.log(url);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cheerio documentation](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#get-i-), `get(i)` retrieves the "DOM" element from the cheerio instance you're working with. The cheerio instance object has an `.attr()` method, but the DOM element is just were they store that object data.

You could use `.first()` instead of `.get(0)`.

Comment: Thanks. 90% of the tutorials just show you '.get' and leave it at that!